# Use browsers' native drop down images/icons in custom control

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking to implement a *true* combobox.  Users can enter text like an input and also click a drop down icon and select a value that way.  I did a quick search and didn't find any pre-existing library I could use for this.  All the ones I found, seem to just be an extension of jQuery's autocomplete where you have to enter a value that is in the autocomplete drop down, but I can't have that restriction.  So I was going to roll my own.

I can easily use a down chevron image from font awesome or the like for the drop down indicator image, but if I could use the browsers' native images, that would be ideal.  Those images are...

... for Firefox:

[image]

... for Chrome:

[image]

... for Safari:

[image]

... and so on.

Is there any way to use the browsers' native images?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is the `DATALIST` element. I believe it was introduced in HTML5 so you may need a fallback/polyfill. But semantically that's probably what you want.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Comment: HTML5 FTW! Great answer, although unfortunately the target browser for my app is IE9.

Comment: Hopefully something here will help you. There are 4 on the list: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#datalist

Comment: Going back to my original question, none of those solutions actually have a drop down icon.  They're all just auto-complete controls that also accept values not in the list.  At this point, I've already rolled my own solution, but I'm just looking to see if I can use the browsers' native drop down icons.